# How can I render a composite (multi-band) raster in true color in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, rasterio

I have gone through most QGIS troubleshooting steps in the GIS stack exchange but have not found a solution. I have imported a composite multi-band spectral GEOTIFF raster as part of the Hansen Global Forest Loss dataset.

https://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.0.html

I have tried many of the various options including **stretching** the min/max values per band, reversing the order of the bands, adjusting the **Statistics extent** and **Accuracy** options, **Blending modes** etc. Nothing seems to be getting the render closer to true color.

QGIS:

[image: QGIS View]

Correct RGB Rendering in Jupyter Notebook with Rasterio (Python):

[image: Python]

Comment: Include the options you have used for showing the image with QGIS and Rasterio as in the screen captures.

Comment: @user2856, was using the landsat "first" granules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS, right click the layer, go to Properties. Change to "Transparency".

For "Custom Transparency Options" change the band to "none" (originally it is set to Band 4 (Alpha) ) and it looks like desired!

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! that was the solution! I'll have to read up on the options here!